# Unale to print an integer array list out of a for loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, printing, int

Code snippet below. I have tried to initialize variable outside of the for loop, but still receive the same error.

I am unable to print the variable array outside the for-loop.

```
public class count_test01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = 2;
        countTest(n);
    }


    public static void countTest(int num){

        //int[] longCnt01_intArray01;

        int cnt01, cnt02;
        long longCnt01, longCnt02;

        longCnt01 = 1;

        // int holds 10 digits in length, MAX is 2,147,483,647.
        // long holds holds 19 digits in length, MAX is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.
        for(int i = 1; i <= 11; i++) { //63; i++) { //(long i = 1; i <= 9000000000000000000L; i++) {            
            longCnt01 *= i; //2; //at 2, i can be <= 63.


            // Convert Integer Count to String.
            String longCnt01String = BigDecimal.valueOf(longCnt01).toPlainString(); 

            //Convert String to Integer Array.
            int[] longCnt01_intArray = new int[longCnt01String.length()];

            for (int i1 = 0; i1 <= longCnt01String.length()-1; i1++){
                longCnt01_intArray[i1] = longCnt01String.charAt(i1) - '0';
            }

            // Create new integer array, save a copy.
            int[] longCnt01_intArray01 = new int[longCnt01_intArray.length];
            for( int i2 = 0; i2 < longCnt01_intArray.length; i2++){

                longCnt01_intArray01[i2] = longCnt01_intArray[i2];
            }

            System.out.println("Count of i           : " + i + "\n");
            System.out.println("Count of longCnt01   : " + longCnt01 + "\n");
            System.out.println("Size of longcnt01    : " + Arrays.toString(longCnt01_intArray) + "\n\n");
        //System.out.println("Size of longCnt01    : " + Arrays.toString(longCnt01_intArray01) + "\n");
        }

        System.out.println("Size of longCnt01    : " + Arrays.toString(longCnt01_intArray01) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Count of longCnt01   : " + longCnt01 + "\n");
}
```

Complaining there is to much code and not enough typed text details.

Comment: One of the essentials of programming is how to declare variables in the correct scope. Why do you ask around the internet for these essentials if you don't even declare `longCnt01_intArray01` in the correct scope? Out of curiosity I copied this code into my IDE. What is "longCnt01_intArray"?

Comment: New to Java. What is the correct scope? Why can I not print an initialized variable outside the for-loop.

Comment: The variable is not visible outside of the loop, why should it be?

Comment: thats what i don't understand. Why shouldn't it be visible? Isn't it a global variable once intialized in the same method?

Comment: Why should it be? And no, the answer to this can be found in any programming tutorial or book available.

Comment: It is not. Java discourages the use of global variables in general. It prefers explicit scope of it's variables. You would need to declare your array up near the `longCnt01` variable for the current print statement to see that array, as in outside the loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks Tim Hunter.

Comment: To be fair to the poster, there are languages that behave differently, so it's not something that "any programming tutorial or book" would explain.  Any *Java* book would.

Comment: Tim Hunter, that doesn't seem to solve the problem. I declared the variable prior to the for-loop. then initalized the variable as  "longCnt01_intArray = new int[longCnt01String.length()];" .   It still complains. Lol. Ahhhhhh. Lol.

Comment: Sorry mate, I just don't have enough info about your program currently. For example, I don't know anything about `longCnt01_intArray`, the array that your internal `longCnt01_intArray01` is based off of. Where is that declared in relation to your method? Also, what is it that you're trying to achieve with this method exactly? Currently you're just making the `longCnt01_intArray01` array, filling it with 0-n values, and then overriding it on the next outer loop iteration.

Comment: I just wanted to create a new int array as a container for future use. This is why I initialized it in the for-loop. Even if I initialize if prior to the for-loop I am unable to print out the values stored outside the for-loop as confirmation values were stored. I am able to print out the int array inside the for-loop only, which is now confusing to me. The code snippet is in a "void method" within the class. Hope that clears things up a little. Just weird for me, new to Java.

Comment: The method starts before the "long lonCnt01" and ends at the bottom of the last "System.out.....". Whats missing in-between is..........                                           String longCnt01String = BigDecimal.valueOf(longCnt01).toPlainString();
            //Convert String to Integer Array.
            int[] longCnt01_intArray = new int[longCnt01String.length()];
            //int[] longCnt01_intArray = new int[longCnt01String.length()];
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 <= longCnt01String.length()-1; i1++){
             longCnt01_intArray[i1] = longCnt01String.charAt(i1) - '0';
  }

Comment: If you're just looking to generate a container for future use, there's no need to populate it with dummy values then. But if you want to keep those dummy values and just generate a random array I would suggest making a method of it and have the method return the generated array. Then you can initialize the array with a given parameter for size, run a for loop to fill it, and then do a few print statements to check its contents before returning it. How I'd do it anyways, if it's a contained set of steps like that.

Comment: Hello Tim, thats what the 2nd "longCnt01_intArray01" does. It contains a mirror image of "longCnt01_intArray". The 2nd for-loop populates the "longCnt01_intArray01" variable. What baffles me is even if I create the variables out of the for-loop(not as an int[] ... = new ....) it does not want to print those values out of the for-loop. If I print both variables within the for-loop(......<= 11...), it prints both integer arrays just fine. Hence why I am scratching my head, and shaking my head in disbelief of its failure to print. after for-loop Thanks for all your input, and suggestions.

Comment: Tim, I posted the whole code as it is. I didn't think I could. If you comment out the 2nd last print and un-comment the print in the for-loop. You will see it works fine. Just not as I indicated. Maybe this will now be more clear.

Comment: I should have also added, I want to save a copy for future use.

Comment: Hey mate, word to the wiser, you need to use the @ symbol in front of my name to actually tag me so I get a notification. Otherwise I won't know you've commented. First thing I wanna comment on is that you should double check your posted code. The `class` section wasn't added to your coded segment and you're missing your closing brackets for the method and class. Please double check to make sure your posted code has things like that, cause otherwise it may come across as a typo error regarding closing brackets and such.

Comment: As for your code, if you want to print the array outside the loop you will need to refactor your code quite a bit since it has a lot of components that are tied to one another. Gimme a bit and I will see if I can detangle it a bit.

Comment: @TimHunter It is there, but for some reason it's not part of the grey field window. It's above and the closing curly brace is below(out of the grey code window). Thanks for your help. Could you also point me to some good literature to get a better grasp on Java. Help is very appreciated.

Comment: To add it to the code section, highlight the entire thing and click the `{}` button on the text editor. The parser for this site checks for a certain amount of spacing to the left of the code to add it to the section. The `{}` button shifts it all over enough.

Comment: @TimHunter, done. Thanks. new to this site also. lol.

Comment: Okay, so let me double check again. What is your end goal for the `longCnt01_intArray01` array? What do you expect it to hold and print at the end?

Comment: @TimHunter, as of now to have an exact copy of "longCnt01_intArray" elements. Which it does in the for-loop. I may need to implement another method and send the copy values to a new method. As of now, I am just trying to make sure my variables are portable and usable for other potential functions. Print being one of them. Thanks.

Comment: @TimHunter,I will give it a try and send you message if I have questions. I am very new to Java, and the coding style of Java is not intuitive to me. Any good books on Java to read is appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I hashed out a working solution of how I would go about it. I refactored a lot of the code though, just to warn you, so please ask if you have any questions or are wondering how to adjust it for your needs should it not quite match what you have in mind.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 2;
    countTest(n);
  }

  public static void countTest(int num) {
    int cnt01, cnt02;
    long longCnt01, longCnt02;

    //Make a scalable arraylist to hold all the copies
    List<Integer[]> copies = new ArrayList<>();

    longCnt01 = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++) { 
      //Moved print here to keep it logically close to it's related component
      System.out.println("Count of i           : " + i + "\n");

      longCnt01 *= i;
      //Moved print here to keep it logically close to it's related component
      System.out.println("Count of longCnt01   : " + longCnt01 + "\n");

      // First thing, refactored the Integer array retrieval into it's own method 
      // and use Integer class instead to make use of a scalable ArrayList
      Integer[] longCnt01_intArray = getIntArrayFromCount(longCnt01);

      // Quick and easy way to make a copy then store in the arraylist for later use
      copies.add(longCnt01_intArray.clone());
    }

    //Use a loop to gro through all copies
    for(int i = 0; i < copies.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println("Size of Copy " + i + ": " + Arrays.toString(copies.get(i)) + "\n");
    }
    System.out.println("Count of longCnt01   : " + longCnt01 + "\n");
  }

  private static Integer[] getIntArrayFromCount(long count) {
    // Convert Integer Count to String.
    String longCnt01String = BigDecimal.valueOf(count).toPlainString();

    // Convert String to Integer Array.
    Integer[] longCnt01_intArray = new Integer[longCnt01String.length()];

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < longCnt01String.length(); i1++) {
      longCnt01_intArray[i1] = longCnt01String.charAt(i1) - '0';
    }

    //Moved print here to keep it logically close to it's related component
    System.out.println("Size of longcnt01    : " + Arrays.toString(longCnt01_intArray) + "\n\n");

    return longCnt01_intArray;
  }
}
```

Comment: I will give it a try and send you message if I have questions. I am very new, and the coding style of Java is not intuitive to me. Thanks again.

Comment: Fantastic results. Is this the typical format of how Java is required to be programmed?????

Comment: What I don't get is why a List declaration is required to store the values, and calling another method for conversion. why does my orig code not function? Since I am just copying my calculated values to another array. This is were my understanding is blocked. My understanding of the coding process suggest it should work just fine. Thanks.

Comment: head scratcher for me is "Integer[] longCnt01_intArray......" in the for-loop and the method.  Aren't these the same? Aggghhhhhh.....Lol.

Comment: Never mind, I see that it is an Array of an Array. Essentially Integer[] longCnt01_intArray becomes an Integer[][] longCnt01_intArray. I figured that out during the print process. It what I was planning on implementing later. Thanks for that.  But my question is still unresolved. Why does Java not allow a printing of a variable copy outside the for-loop. That is what is baffling me. Thanks for all your help and foresight.

Comment: It has to do with the scope. Java allows the copies to be printed in my example because I declared the List outside of the loop so it can see the reference to the List regardless of what I put in that list. The original array on the other hand was having issues because not only did the copy need to be declared outside the loop for anything outside the loop to see it (such as the print statements), your copy was trying to reference other values also declared inside the loop so it was highly coupled to that loop body.

Comment: @LennySquiggy Tagging you in this one since I forgot to in the original. Can't remember if it sends a notification for answer comments to the OP if not tagged. To further clarify, it sees the value in my example since the List is declared outside the loop and the List creates it's own references to the value given to it through it's methods so when I add something to it that value becomes accessible via the `get()` method call so long as the List object is accessible to the given scope.

Comment: More scope information can be found in the [tutorial here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/). In particular, you ran head first into an issue regarding Block Scope.

Comment: So initializing variable arrays outside the loop still will not work. I would need to create an object scope outside the loop first. Is that correct to say?

Comment: @LennySquiggy In order for anything outside a code block (a code block being anything inside `{ }` brackets) to see a variable, the variable needs to be declared outside that code block. It does not necessarily need to be given a value, ie. `int x = 10;`, but it does need to be declared, ie. `int x;`. If you want it to be seen outside the code block, then declare it outside the code block or pass it to a storage construct created in the wanted scope (like a List) that creates it's own reference to the value via methods and internal storage.

Comment: Thanks for clarity.